# Cite a song using apa6, apacite, and bibtex

Tags: bibtex, apa6

I'm using apaciteThe `apacite` package documentation indicates I need the `apacdoc` package to cite songs, so I've included that as well.  What's not clear to me is which bibtex fields should be added for the album and recording date.

dessa.bib:

```
@misc{mineshaft,
  author="Dessa",
  title="Mineshaft"
  year="2010",
}
```

dessa.tex:

```
\documentclass[man,12pt,apacite]{apa6}
\usepackage{apacite}
\usepackage{apacdoc}
\usepackage{url}

\title{The Title}
\shorttitle{Title}
\author{Insyte}
\affiliation{My School}
\note{\today}

\begin{document}
\maketitle

Dessa is a Minneapolis native ``underrated writer, overrated rapper''
\citesong{mineshaft} who performs with the alt-hip-hop collective, Doomtree.

\bibliography{dessa}
\end{document}
```

The output I get from that is this:

> Dessa is a Minneapolis native “underrated writer, overrated rapper”
>   Dessa who performs with the alt-hip-hop collective, Doomtree.

Note the citation consists of just the string "Dessa," without parenthesis or the rest of the citation. Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For citing songs, `apacdoc` provides the command:

```
\bibsong{author}{year}{song title}{track info}
```

and you should refer to it through a `key` field in this way:

```
key = {{\protect\bibsong{author}{year}{song title}{track info}}}
```

So, your `dessa.bib` can be changed to:

```
@incollection{mineshaft,
  key = {{\protect\bibsong{Dessa}{2010}{Mineshaft}{track~1}}}
}
```

There is just one problem: `\bibsong` command was thought to cite classical music and has a 4th argument for the number of the track. But you can change that argument to whatever you want (e.g. album, label).